# Google Closure Compiler extern file for MooTools framework

Tags: javascript, mootools, minify, google-closure-compiler

Google Closure Compiler in advanced optimization mode uses a file to define externs that would prevent variable, property and function names that refer to symbols in an external library to be minified, thereby breaking code. My goal is to compile code that uses the MooTools framework (versions 1.2 and 1.3) yet I am unable to find an "official" extern file that would prevent references to MooTools functions from being obfuscated when my code is fed to the closure compiler. I have come up with the following rather rudimentary custom extern file that successfully processes my file but is there a better alternative (such as auto-generating it from MooTools source)?

```
//
// Number
//

/**
* @param {number} min
* @param {number} max
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.limit = function (min, max) {}
/**
* @param {number=} precision
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.round = function (precision) {}
Number.prototype.times = function () {}
/**
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.toFloat = function () {}
/**
* @param {number=} base
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.toInt = function (base) {}

//
// Number.Math
//

/**
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.abs = function () {}
/**
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.acos = function () {}
/**
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.asin = function () {}
/**
* @param {number} x
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.atan2 = function (x) {}
/**
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.ceil = function () {}
/**
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.cos = function () {}
/**
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.exp = function () {}
/**
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.floor = function () {}
/**
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.log = function () {}
/**
* @param {...number} x
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.max = function (x) {}
/**
* @param {...number} x
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.min = function (x) {}
/**
* @param {number} x
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.pow = function (x) {}
/**
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.sin = function () {}
/**
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.sqrt = function () {}
/**
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
Number.prototype.tan = function () {}

//
// String
//

/**
* @return {boolean}
* @nosideeffects
*/
String.prototype.test = function () {}
/**
* @return {boolean}
* @nosideeffects
*/
String.prototype.contains = function () {}
/**
* @return {string}
* @nosideeffects
* @suppress {duplicate}
*/
String.prototype.trim = function () {}
/**
* @return {string}
* @nosideeffects
*/
String.prototype.clean = function () {}
/**
* @return {string}
* @nosideeffects
*/
String.prototype.camelCase = function () {}
/**
* @return {string}
* @nosideeffects
*/
String.prototype.hyphenate = function () {}
/**
* @return {string}
* @nosideeffects
*/
String.prototype.capitalize = function () {}
/**
* @return {string}
* @nosideeffects
*/
String.prototype.escapeRegExp = function () {}
/**
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
String.prototype.toInt = function () {}
/**
* @return {number}
* @nosideeffects
*/
String.prototype.toFloat = function () {}
/**
* @return {(string|Array.<number>)}
* @nosideeffects
*/
String.prototype.hexToRgb = function () {}
/**
* @return {(string|Array.<string>)}
* @nosideeffects
*/
String.prototype.rgbToHex = function () {}
/**
* @return {string}
* @nosideeffects
*/
String.prototype.substitute = function () {}
/**
* @return {string}
* @nosideeffects
*/
String.prototype.stripScripts = function () {}

//
// Array
//

/**
* @param {function(*, number=, Array=) : undefined} fn
* @param {!Object=} bind
*/
Array.prototype.each = function (fn, bind) {}
Array.prototype.invoke = function () {}
/**
* @param {function(*, number=, Array=) : boolean} fn
* @param {!Object=} bind
* @return {boolean}
* @suppress {duplicate}
*/
Array.prototype.every = function (fn, bind) {}
/**
* @param {function(*, number=, Array=) : boolean} fn
* @param {!Object=} bind
* @return {Array}
* @suppress {duplicate}
*/
Array.prototype.filter = function (fn, bind) {}
/**
* @return Array
*/
Array.prototype.clean = function () {}
/**
* @param {*} item
* @param {number} from
* @return number
* @suppress {duplicate}
*/
Array.prototype.indexOf = function (item, from) {}
/**
* @param {function(*, number=, Array=) : *} fn
* @param {!Object=} bind
* @return {Array}
* @suppress {duplicate}
*/
Array.prototype.map = function (fn, bind) {}
/**
* @param {function(*, number=, Array=) : boolean} fn
* @param {!Object=} bind
* @return {boolean}
* @suppress {duplicate}
*/
Array.prototype.some = function (fn, bind) {}
/**
* @param {Array} obj
* @return {Object}
*/
Array.prototype.associate = function (obj) {}
/**
* @param {Object} obj
* @return {Object}
*/
Array.prototype.link = function (obj) {}
/**
* @param {*} item
* @param {number} from
* @return {boolean}
*/
Array.prototype.contains = function (item, from) {}
/**
* @param {Array} other
* @return {Array}
*/
Array.prototype.append = function (other) {}
/**
* @return {*}
*/
Array.prototype.getLast = function () {}
/**
* @return {*}
*/
Array.prototype.getRandom = function () {}
/**
* @param {*} item
* @return {Array}
*/
Array.prototype.include = function (item) {}
/**
* @param {Array} other
* @return {Array}
*/
Array.prototype.combine = function (other) {}
/**
* @param {*} item
* @return {Array}
*/
Array.prototype.erase = function (item) {}
/**
* @return {Array}
*/
Array.prototype.empty = function () {}
/**
* @return {Array}
*/
Array.prototype.flatten = function () {}
/**
* @return {*}
*/
Array.prototype.pick = function () {}
Array.prototype.hexToRgb = function () {}
Array.prototype.rgbToHex = function () {}

// Class

/**
* @constructor
* @param {(!Object|function())} properties
*/
function Class(properties) { }
/**
* @param {!Object} properties
*/
Class.prototype.implement = function (properties) {}

/**
* @constructor
*/
function Events() { }
/**
* @constructor
*/
function Options() { }

//
// Element
//

/**
* @constructor
* @param {(string|Element)} el
* @param {!Object=} properties
* @suppress {duplicate}
*/
function Element(el, properties) { }
/**
* @param {string} tag
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.getElement = function (tag) {}
/**
* @param {string} tag
* @return {Elements}
*/
Element.prototype.getElements = function (tag) {}
/**
* @param {string} id
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.getElementById = function (id) {}
/**
* @param {(string|!Object)} property
* @param {*=} value
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.set = function (property, value) {}
/**
* @param {string} property
* @return {*}
*/
Element.prototype.get = function (property) {}
/**
* @param {string} property
* @return {*}
*/
Element.prototype.erase = function (property) {}
/**
* @param {(string|Element)} match
* @return {boolean}
*/
Element.prototype.match = function (match) {}
/**
* @param {(string|Element)} el
* @return {boolean}
* @suppress {duplicate}
*/
Element.prototype.contains = function (el) {}
/**
* @param {(string|Element)} el
* @param {string=} where
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.inject = function (el, where) {}
/**
* @param {(string|Element)} el
* @param {string=} where
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.grab = function (el, where) {}
/**
* @param {(string|Element|Elements)} el
* @param {...(string|Element|Elements)} var_args
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.adopt = function (el,var_args) {}
/**
* @param {(string|Element)} el
* @param {string=} where
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.wraps = function (el, where) {}
/**
* @param {string} text
* @param {string=} where
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.appendText = function (text, where) {}
/**
* @return {undefined}
*/
Element.prototype.dispose = function () {}
/**
* @param {boolean=} contents
* @param {boolean=} keepid
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.clone = function (contents, keepid) {}
/**
* @param {(string|Element)} el
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.replaces = function (el) {}
/**
* @param {string} className
* @return {boolean}
*/
Element.prototype.hasClass = function (className) {}
/**
* @param {string} className
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.addClass = function (className) {}
/**
* @param {string} className
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.removeClass = function (className) {}
/**
* @param {string} className
* @param {boolean=} force
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.toggleClass = function (className, force) {}
/**
* @param {string=} match
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.getPrevious = function (match) {}
/**
* @param {string=} match
* @return {Elements}
*/
Element.prototype.getAllPrevious = function (match) {}
/**
* @param {string=} match
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.getNext = function (match) {}
/**
* @param {string=} match
* @return {Elements}
*/
Element.prototype.getAllNext = function (match) {}
/**
* @param {string=} match
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.getFirst = function (match) {}
/**
* @param {string=} match
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.getLast = function (match) {}
/**
* @param {string=} match
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.getParent = function (match) {}
/**
* @param {string=} match
* @return {Elements}
*/
Element.prototype.getParents = function (match) {}
/**
* @param {string=} match
* @return {Elements}
*/
Element.prototype.getSiblings = function (match) {}
/**
* @param {string=} match
* @return {Elements}
*/
Element.prototype.getChildren = function (match) {}
/**
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.empty = function () {}
Element.prototype.destroy = function () {}
/**
* @return {string}
*/
Element.prototype.toQueryString = function () {}
Element.prototype.getSelected = function () {}
/**
* @param {string} property
* @return {string}
*/
Element.prototype.getProperty = function (property) {}
/**
* @param {Array.<string>} properties
* @return {!Object}
*/
Element.prototype.getProperties = function (properties) {}
/**
* @param {string} property
* @param {*} value
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.setProperty = function (property, value) {}
/**
* @param {!Object} properties
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.setProperties = function (properties) {}
/**
* @param {string} property
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.removeProperty = function (property) {}
/**
* @param {Array.<string>} properties
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.removeProperties = function (properties) {}
/**
* @param {string} key
* @param {*} value
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.store = function (key, value) {}
/**
* @param {string} key
* @param {*=} def
* @return {*}
*/
Element.prototype.retrieve = function (key, def) {}
/**
* @param {string} key
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.eliminate = function (key) {}

/**
* @constructor
* @extends Array
*/
function Elements() { }
/**
* @param {(string|!Object)} property
* @param {*=} value
* @return {Element}
*/
Elements.prototype.set = function (property, value) {}
/**
* @param {string} className
* @return {Element}
*/
Elements.prototype.addClass = function (className) {}
/**
* @param {string} className
* @return {Element}
*/
Elements.prototype.removeClass = function (className) {}
/**
* @param {string} className
* @param {boolean=} force
* @return {Element}
*/
Elements.prototype.toggleClass = function (className, force) {}

/**
* @param {(string|Element)} arg
* @return {Element}
*/
function $(arg) {}
/**
* @param {(string|Array|Element|Elements)} arg
* @param {...Element} var_args
* @return {Elements}
*/
function $$(arg, var_args) {}

//
// Element.Style
//

/**
* @param {string} property
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.setStyle = function (property, value) {}
/**
* @param {string} property
* @return {string}
*/
Element.prototype.getStyle = function (property) {}
/**
* @param {!Object} styles
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.setStyles = function (styles) {}
/**
* @param {...string} var_args
*/
Element.prototype.getStyles = function (var_args) {}

//
// Element.Event
//

/**
* @param {string} type
* @param {function()} fn
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.addEvent = function (type, fn) {}
/**
* @param {string} type
* @param {function()} fn
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.removeEvent = function (type, fn) {}
/**
* @param {!Object} events
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.addEvents = function (events) {}
/**
* @param {(string|!Object)=} events
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.removeEvents = function (events) {}
/**
* @param {string} type
* @param {(Array|Object)=} args
* @param {number=} delay
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.fireEvent = function (type, args, delay) {}
/**
* @param {Element} from
* @param {string} type
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.cloneEvents = function (from, type) {}

/**
* @param {string} type
* @param {function()} fn
*/
window.addEvent = function (type, fn) {}
/**
* @param {string} type
* @param {function()} fn
*/
window.removeEvent = function (type, fn) {}
/**
* @param {!Object} events
*/
window.addEvents = function (events) {}
/**
* @param {(string|!Object)=} events
*/
window.removeEvents = function (events) {}
/**
* @param {string} type
* @param {(Array|Object)=} args
* @param {number=} delay
*/
window.fireEvent = function (type, args, delay) {}
/**
* @param {Element} from
* @param {string} type
*/
window.cloneEvents = function (from, type) {}

//
// Element.Dimensions
//

Element.prototype.scrollTo = function () {}
Element.prototype.getSize = function () {}
Element.prototype.getScrollSize = function () {}
Element.prototype.getScroll = function () {}
Element.prototype.getPosition = function () {}
Element.prototype.setPosition = function () {}
Element.prototype.getCoordinates = function () {}
Element.prototype.getOffsetParent = function () {}

window.scrollTo = function () {}
window.getSize = function () {}
window.getScrollSize = function () {}
window.getScroll = function () {}

//
// Fx
//

/**
* @constructor
*/
function Fx() {}
/**
* @constructor
* @param {(string|Element)} el
* @param {!Object=} options
*/
Fx.Tween = function (el, options) { }
Fx.Tween.prototype.set = function () { }
Fx.Tween.prototype.start = function () { }
/**
* @constructor
* @param {(string|Element)} el
* @param {!Object=} options
*/
Fx.Morph = function (el, options) { }
/**
* @param {(string|!Object)} properties
* @return {Fx.Morph}
*/
Fx.Morph.prototype.set = function (properties) { }
/**
* @param {(string|!Object)} properties
* @return {Fx.Morph}
*/
Fx.Morph.prototype.start = function (properties) { }

/**
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.tween = function () {}
/**
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.morph = function () {}
/**
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.fade = function () {}
/**
* @return {Element}
*/
Element.prototype.highlight = function () {}

//
// Fx.Transitions
//

/**
* @constructor
*/
Fx.Transitions = function () {}
Fx.Transitions.linear = function () {}
Fx.Transitions.quad = function () {}
Fx.Transitions.cubic = function () {}
Fx.Transitions.quart = function () {}
Fx.Transitions.quint = function () {}
Fx.Transitions.pow = function () {}
Fx.Transitions.expo = function () {}
Fx.Transitions.circ = function () {}
Fx.Transitions.sine = function () {}
Fx.Transitions.back = function () {}
Fx.Transitions.bounce = function () {}
Fx.Transitions.elastic = function () {}

//
// Request
//

/**
* @constructor
* @param {!Object=} options
*/
function Request(options) { }
Request.prototype.setHeader = function () {}
Request.prototype.getHeader = function () {}
Request.prototype.send = function () {}
Request.prototype.post = function () {}
Request.prototype.get = function () {}
Request.prototype.put = function () {}
Request.prototype.cancel = function () {}
Request.prototype.isRunning = function () {}

Element.prototype.send = function () {}

/**
* @constructor
* @extends Request
* @param {!Object=} options
*/
Request.HTML = function (options) { }
/**
* @constructor
* @extends Request
* @param {!Object=} options
*/
Request.JSON = function (options) { }

//
// JSON
//

/**
* @constructor
*/
function JSON() { }
/**
* @param {Object} obj
* @return {string}
*/
JSON.encode = function (obj) {}
/**
* @param {string} string
* @param {boolean=} secure
*/
JSON.decode = function (string, secure) {}

//
// Swiff
//

/**
* @constructor
* @param {string} path
* @param {!Object} options
*/
function Swiff(path, options) { }

//
// Compat
//

/**
* @param {...*} var_args
* @nosideeffects
*/
function $pick(var_args) { }
/**
* @param {...Object} var_args
* @nosideeffects
*/
function $merge(var_args) { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comprehensive extens file is just the first step of using the Closure Compiler in Advanced mode.  The library itself has to be written (or modified) to be useable.

An externs file merely prevents one sort of problem only -- that of property and function renaming.  However, some code constructs may break after compilation if the library code base is not carefully scrubbed.

For example, dead-code removal can easily remove the wrong code (or leave along code that should be removed).  Unintended aliases can prevent most optimizations from happening.  "Dangerous use of this" can break code in the most unsuspecting places.

Therefore, even if your code compiles and work fine with your externs file, it doesn't mean that other MooTools programs will work fine.  Moreover, it doesn't mean that the next revision of your program will not break when you unknowingly uses a feature that breaks under compilation.

Comment: I certainly cannot affect how the MooTools framework is implemented and my only goal indeed was to use property and function name minification without compromising the interoperability with MooTools. As far as I can see, always passing string literals as property names in objects passed to MooTools methods does keep my code functionally unchanged by minification, I do not see how unintended dead code removal or "dangerous" use of `this` might come up as problems but truly I am no expert of the closure compiler. Thanks for the warning though.

Comment: @boroka, good effort for you to bring MooTools with the Closure Compiler.  I myself is leading an effort in modifying Dojo for the compiler.  Learnt the hard why what things can happen -- you won't believe some of the subtle bugs created after compilation, especially when you have a huge project already written. Some bugs took days to track down, only due to a small unrenamed property buried deep in the library somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

The closure compiler contributed externs files go in http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fcontrib%2Fexterns .  As you can see there are a number of externs files for popular libraries in there.

If you have something that work, go ahead and use it, and maybe send a patch to the closure compilers people with your mootools externs.  That way a bunch of people can help maintain it.  They're happy to receive patches as uploads to issues : http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/list